# POST ISSET on same page?

Tags: php, html, sql

i'm trying to make a button execute a function in my database but I cant seem to get this ISSET to fire off. What am I doing wrong? the echo doesn't come up on my page either.

```
<form action="" name="stack" method="post">
<?PHP //echo "<input type=hidden name=customerx value=$Customer>"?>
     <input id="stack" class="submit3" type="submit" value="Stack my GI" />
</form>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['stack'])){
 $sqlcall = "{CALL WEB_StackGI(?)}";
 $sqlargs = array(
 array($Customer,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
 );
 $query = sqlsrv_query($conexion,$sqlcall, $sqlargs)or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
 $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
 echo "<b> Successfully stacked GI</b>";
 }
?>
```

Customer is defined in the beginning of the page.

```
$Customer = $_SESSION['IdCustomer'];
```

Comment: you have no name attribute on that input. no name = no post value

Comment: thanks. I posted as an answer so you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="stack" name="stack" class="submit3" type="submit" value="Stack my GI" />
```

You left off the name attribute. Without that it will not send that field in the post array

Comment: Plus, OP has the same name in the form `<form action="" name="stack" method="post">` it's to be removed. Also, the form tag does not use the name attribute.